# using async-await to wait for an assignment inside a function in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function that does 2 things. I want to wait for the first line and then execute the second line. The first line is a simple assignment. How can I do this using async-await without making the first assignment a function. The following code gives me an error in line 2.

```
async eg(){
    await a = b;
    c.focus();
}
```

Comment: You don't have to wait for an assignment. Assignments are synchronous anyway so it'll always 'wait' for it finish before proceeding to the next line.

Comment: If neither of the two things that the function does is asynchronous, you don't need - and should not use - `async`/`await`.

Comment: I have a div with `v-if` that comes true only when a is equal to b. when that happens a pop up shows that contains c and then I want the focus to move to the c. Without the async-await it doesn't work

Comment: Agreed with the two previous comments: you don't need `await` for an assignment. Can you post an extract of your template? It might be related to some "Component does not update when I want to" question. Stuff like `this.$nextTick();` can help.

Comment: Await should go on the right-hand side. a = await b

Comment: @Al-un 's approach worked very well

Comment: Thanks @mha. For the sake of future readers, can you add more details to your details? `$nextTick()` can address multiple issues so it is difficult to see to which problem it answers. Then this question might be a duplicate of or just derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55932110/4906586

Comment: Also, either please expand your answer and accept or I'll write an answer but this question should be marked as "closed"

Comment: Accepted ChrisWong's answer as the complete one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eg() {
  this.a = this.b;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.$refs["c"].focus();
  }, 1);
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-focus-ybbqf)

Answer (score 0):

As user Al-un mentioned using `this.$nextTick();` solved it beautifully.